# Plot graph of difference in one column for grouped columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, a simplified example is below:

```
   cycle  sensor  value
0      0       1   0.34
1      0       1   0.80
2      0       2   0.12
3      0       2   0.62
4      1       1   0.01
5      1       1   0.75
6      1       2   0.06
7      1       2   0.02
```

I'd like to plot the difference of the "value" column for each sensor, for each cycle: have x-axis as cycle number, y-axis as the difference in value, each series would be a given sensor number. e.g. the line for sensor one would be 0.46 and 0.74 over cycles 0 and 1.

In reality, I have many more columns (not used for this part of my code) and there are 144 cycles and 37 cycles. There are a few thousand values per sensor per cycle.

This is the code I have written, I don't get an error: a figure is created but no data shows.

```
groups = unstacked_data.groupby(["cycle", "pressure"])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("Cycle Number")
ax.set_ylabel("Change in Normalised Pressure")


for cycle, group in groups:
        ax.plot(cycle[0],group.value.max()-group.value.min(), label=group.pressure)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any advice would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think now I get it. Should the result look like this?

```
diff = df.groupby(["sensor","cycle"]).apply(lambda x:x.value.max()-x.value.min()).unstack()

#Output: each value in the table is max-min. Columns are cycles and rows are sensors
    cycle   0         1
sensor      
1          0.46     0.74
2          0.50     0.04
```

And now you can plot it by row, i.e. by sensor.

Comment: Thanks, that does plot it as a scatter, but what I'm hoping for is that each pressure number will be a series so I get a line that connects the values. So for my example, I would have 2 lines across 2  cycles. In reality I want 144 lines across the 37 cycles.

Comment: I managed to "fix" the code above, by adding in the marker size, but I still can't get the lines to make the series. ax.plot(pressure_cycle[1],group.value.max()-group.value.min(), marker = 'o', linestyle = 'solid', markersize = 0.5)

Comment: In the example above pressure is the column value? In your example each group of cycle/value consists of one element and you cannot make a plot out of one point

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In reality I have 37 cycles and 144 sensors. Each sensor has multiple readings per cycle. I want to plot the change in value of each sensor for each cycle. So I would have 144 lines, each with 37 marker points. Does that make sense? Above is just a small example of the dataframe structure.

Comment: I think here the problem is your groupby. You need to group just by "cycle". I updated my answer. Check it out.